# Which was Destro (Re-Destro's father)'s quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Re-Destro's father, Destro, it's said that it was one of the most powerful villains, compared to All For One.

Which was his quirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoriyoshi Nakajima also known as Destro, is the leader of a paramillitary terrorist group called the Quirk Liberation Army.

- **Generic capacitie**s: Physically, is stronger and faster than the average, also 
  mentally remains very sane.
- **Charisma**: Even more dangerous than its peculiarity is Destro's ability to convince 
  others to fight  and die the name of their cause. It has a huge power of persuasion, 
  and can be very convincing.
- **Quirk**: Pyrotechnics power, Destro can generate and launch bombs, explosives, and 
   other volatile constructs that have various yields from his body and then can 
   manipulate them. Destro's bombs don't need to detonate on impact, he can make them 
  explode immediately after leaving his body he can set them on a timer or can detoante 
  them remotely whenever he feels like it.

[image]

Sources: Me, Manga and https://myheroacademiafanon.fandom.com/wiki/Destro